# Getting Incorrect Results with R Neuralnet packages

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

Running the following code in R to train a neural network to classify handwriting. There are 63 columns of which the 63rd is the classification ranging from 0 to 9

```
library(neuralnet)
data <- read.csv("handwriting.csv")
index <- sample(1:nrow(data),round(0.75*nrow(data)))
train <- data[index,]
test <- data[-index,]
n <- names(train)
f <- as.formula(paste("a63 ~", paste(n[!n %in% "a63"], collapse = " + ")))
nn <- neuralnet(f,data=train, hidden=2, linear.output=F, act.fct = "logistic", err.fct="ce")
plot(nn)
pr.nn <- compute(nn,test[, -63])
predicted <- pr.nn$net.result
results <- cbind(predicted, test$a63)
results
```

The output I get at the last step is as follows

```
4480 0.9999991455    0
4482 0.9999991455    2
4490 0.9999991455    0
4492 0.9999991455    2
4494 0.9999991455    4
```

The first column with decimals is the predicted results, this is not what I expect though because the results are supposed to be categorical like in the last column not decimals, when I change linear.output = TRUE, I get closer values but this is not the correct interpretation as my intention is to classify

Comment: "Incorrect results" is an inflammatory question title, and has a very different meaning from "not what I expect".

Answer (score 0):

R doesn't know 0-9 in your csv is a categorical variable. You have to coerce it to a factor. Right now you're predicting a continuous value. It helps to do some amount of exploratory analysis before jumping straight to predictive modeling, including making sure you're using the correct datatypes with a call to the class() function.